# Why letter-spacing doesn't work in Fx <10

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using Fx 9 and my following code breaks in it while it works in all other browsers including IE9.

**EDIT**
Please note that I just want to know about this particular code breaking not interested in how to actually get work done because I am learning CSS not doing work for any client.

HTML

```
<form id="sform" action="index.htm">
<input class="sfield" type="text" value="Search..." />
<input class="sbutton" type="button" value="Go" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
#sform {
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
    padding: 10px 10px;    
    border-radius: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background: #f1f1f1;    
    letter-spacing: -4px;

}
:not(#sform){  
    letter-spacing: -4px;
}
.sfield {
    padding: 6px 35px 6px 8px;        
    border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;    
    width: 202px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.sbutton {
    color: #fff;
    background: #5f5f5f;
    margin-left: -52px;
    border: solid 1px #494949;
    height: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UfK6K/8/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your code breaking.

Comment: I meant by that button is not kept in line and pushed to the next line.

Comment: I can't explain why your use of letter-spacing isn't quite working how you want because it's a very unusual way of trying to achieve what you are trying to achieve. I know you're not looking for a solution but this is how I would have done it http://jsfiddle.net/UfK6K/12/

Comment: Its right that I am not looking for solution but rather learn about underlying reasoning that would help me to find solutions myself. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of your testcase will depend on the precise font size the user has set and the font that gets used.  It will also depend on how the UA decides to handle negative letter spacing; the spec allows it to be capped or ignored altogether.  From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#spacing-props :

> This value indicates inter-character space *in addition to* the default space between characters. Values may be negative, but there may be implementation-specific limits.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `letter-spacing` there anyway? I don't see the logic behind this decision.
I think you may have to rework that code, try with something like this, it's cleaner and it should work in all browsers, IE8+ just fine. Adjust to your needs:

**html**

```
<form id="sform" action="index.htm">
    <input class="sfield" type="text" value="Search..." />
    <input class="sbutton" type="button" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**css**

```
#sform, .sfield, .sbutton {
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#sform {
    position: relative;                
    display: inline-block;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.sfield {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 300px;
}

.sbutton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    border: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

**explanation:**

Letter spacing increases or decreases the space between characters in a text and it seems you're using it to add padding.
Then, an absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.
Try removing all your `letter-spacing` and you'll see that the changes in the layout are minimal.
Take a look at my example and by logic you'll figure it out why it works.

**example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/7KGkJ/1/

Comment: Thanks.. but any thoughts about that particular code breaking because I am keen to learn about why things go wrong with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.sbutton`.
Is that the desired outcome?

Comment: Yep, its desired outcome. BUT why it is needed to put position:absolute to make it work in FX while it worked in all other browsers? I am interested in learning the POINT.

Comment: Different browsers use different render engines. I can't tell you who is right in this instance (Firefox or the others), one would have to look at the standard to find out. So the answer to 'why' is: either Firefox does it wrong or the others are doing it wrong.